# Query is not returning the correct count while joining two tables in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

- Table A has 2500 rows
- Table B has 12000 rows

Common column between these two tables is `Email_ID`.

**Note**: `Email ID` column may have nulls in table B.

If I join these tables using this query

```
Select count(*) 
from A 
left join B on A.Email_ID = B.Email_ID
```

it is returning a value of more than 2500 records.

But I want only 2500 records from Table A

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) JOIN and count(*) can be tricky. (1-to-1, 1-to-many, many-to-many etc.)

Comment: A JOIN will return one row for *every* match which means you can get a lot more than 2500 rows if the same IDs are repeated. If you want only the As that exist in B, you'll have to use an `EXISTS` or `IN` clause

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 2):

`*` will return total record count regardless of duplicate or nulls :

```
Select count(b.Email_ID) -- if you have a duplicate email ids then use `distinct`
from A left join 
     B 
     on A.Email_ID = B.Email_ID;
```

However, you can also use `exists`, join will return multiple rows if `b` table has more rows matching email id available in table `a`. So, count will always be increased.

```
select count(a.Email_ID)
from a 
where exists (select 1 from b where b.Email_ID =  a.Email_ID);
```

Comment: `WHERE a.Email_ID IN (select Email_ID from b)` should produce the same execution plan

Comment: *Should* I agree, but `EXISTS` vs `IN` is somewhat of a preference thing, @PanagiotisKanavos . Personally (like Yogesh appears to) I prefer `EXISTS` as when you use `NOT EXISTS` it doesn't give "unexpected" results when the are `NULL` values.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 2,500 hundred records, then why are you joining?  That is, these return 2,500:

```
select count(*)
from A;

select count(distinct A.Email_id) 
from A left join
     B
     on A.Email_ID = B.Email_ID;
```

If you actually want one row returned from `B` for each `A`, then use `outer apply` rather than `left join`:

```
select . . .
from a outer apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from b
      where b.email_id = a.email_id
     ) b;
```

This returns an arbitrary matching row from `b`.  Normally, the subquery would have an `order by` to provide more control over the matching row.  For instance, `order by newid()` would return a *random* row.